# How can I limit textfield size to the size of its content in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout

In Flutter, if I have a textfield, It expands to a fixed height and tries to fill the container, and in case it is not in a constrained container it throws an error.

Is there a way however to constrain the size of a textfield to its content, like the picture below?

[image]

Comment: What if it's empty?

Comment: That's a good question, I checked how the example I put in the question (figma) handles it. The text itself has size 0 but there is a bit of padding around it so the whole field is very narrow and one-line tall.

Comment: Can you include your attempt with issue.?